# Need SQL query for Comparing Duplicate Value and print respective column name

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

HI expert and need your help me on the below requirement in oracle.

1. I have list of columns and from that I need to know based on the Model No. column filter if the other columns have any duplicate values, if yes then it should display comments column as Column Name + duplicate value (Ex: Category_description having duplicate value)
2. If the any of the column is blank it should print Column Name is blank (Ex: Parent Category ID has blank value).

The data is:

```
M_No    CAT_DESC              CAT_ID    P_CAT_ID    Comments
1       computer hardware     10        90  
1       monitors              11        10  
1       printers              12        10  
1       harddisks             13        10        CAT_DESC duplicate
1       memory components     14        10  
1       harddisks             15        10        CAT_DESC duplicate
1       keyboards, mouses     16        10  
1       other peripherals     17        10  
1       harddisks             19        10        CAT_DESC duplicate
2       office fur supplies   30        90  
2       capitalizable assets  31        30  
2       office daily use      32        30  
2       manuals, other books  33        30      CAT_DESC, CAT_ID duplicate
2       manuals, other books  33        30      CAT_DESC, CAT_ID duplicate
3       computer hardware     90                 P_CAT_ID is blank value
4       computer software     20        90  
4       spreadsheet software  21        20  
4       processing software   22        20  
4                             23                CAT_DESC, P_CAT_ID is blank 
4      operating systems      24        20  
4      software development   25        20  
4      miscellaneous software 29        20
```

Comment: Please some one help me on this query